# Are there any packages to create custom table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I understand that this is quite a broad question, but here's my use case: I'm writing a class to typeset a journal issue, and I need a (customized) ToC.  There are a few "types" of articles (e.g. a usual article, a letter to the editor, an obituary, a book review, etc.), and each of these needs an entry in the ToC with specific metadata etc.  Are there any packages that might help here?  (Previously, I did it on my own, but now I'm redesigning the class basically from scratch, using better techniques – like `xparse` or `etoolbox` as opposed to lots of `\futurelet`s and `\expandafter`s, for instance – and I was wondering whether there might be something nice in the ToC department, too.)

Comment: see package `titletoc`

Answer (score 4):

There are some packages.

- [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)
- [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)
- [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc)
- [`tocstyle`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/) (part of the KOMA-bundle)